# Using JSONEncoder to encode a variable with Codable as type

Tags: ios, swift, serialization, protocols, codable

I managed to get both JSON and plist encoding and decoding working, but only by directly calling the encode/decode function on a specific object.

For example:

```
struct Test: Codable {
    var someString: String?
}

let testItem = Test()
testItem.someString = "abc"

let result = try JSONEncoder().encode(testItem)
```

This works well and without issues.

However, I am trying to get a function that takes in only the `Codable` protocol conformance as type and saves that object.

```
func saveObject(_ object: Encodable, at location: String) {
    // Some code

    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(object)

    // Some more code
}
```

This results in the following error:

> Cannot invoke 'encode' with an argument list of type '(Encodable)'

Looking at the definition of the encode function, it seems as if it should be able to accept `Encodable`, unless `Value` is some strange type I don't know of.

```
open func encode<Value>(_ value: Value) throws -> Data where Value : Encodable
```

Comment: [Protocols don't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878), so you cannot substitute in `Encodable` for the generic placeholder `Value`, as `Encodable` is not a type that conforms to `Encodable`. Just use a generic placeholder, as vadian says.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use a generic type constrained to `Encodable`

```
func saveObject<T : Encodable>(_ object: T, at location: String) {
    //Some code

    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(object)

    //Some more code
}
```

Comment: Of course, thank you, I am still new to Swift and I completely forgot this is how it's done.

Comment: what the? could someone explain me this behaviour? it doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: Codable needs to be able to determine its object type. Using `Any` as the type confuses it because it doesn't know which type's `init(from decoder:)` initialiser to call. This function essentially provides the missing information in the form of a generic. The code can calculate which type to use through type inference.

Comment: it need to know (or to infer) the type you wanna encode, because if you have `var x: Encodable = myXStruct(); ` and  `var y: Encodable = myYStruct(); `. the encode function wont know what is that. is it x or y. so you should look up generic functions and Protocols with associated types (PAT)

Comment: What is the syntax for doing this in a property getter rather than a function?

Comment: @pkamb Sorry I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Something like `var object<T : Encodable>: T {`, which doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a different approach to that extending the Encodable protocol with all the instance methods you might need. Expanding on that you can add a parameter to your methods to pass a custom encoder and provide a default encoder as well to all of them:

```
extension DataProtocol {
    var string: String? { String(bytes: self, encoding: .utf8) }
}
```

---

```
extension Encodable {
    func data(using encoder: JSONEncoder = JSONEncoder()) throws -> Data { try encoder.encode(self) }
    func string(using encoder: JSONEncoder = JSONEncoder()) throws -> String { try data(using: encoder).string ?? "" }
}
```

---

Usage

```
let message = ["key":["a","b","c"]]

let jsonData = try! message.data() // 21 bytes [123, 34, 107, 101, 121, 34, 58, 91, 34, 97, 34, 44, 34, 98, 34, 44, 34, 99, 34, 93, 125]
let jsonString = try! message.string()  // "{"key":["a","b","c"]}"
```

Example when passing a date with a default encoder. Note that the dateEncodingStrategy used is the default (a Double representing the timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate):

```
let message = ["createdAt": Date()]

let jsonData = try! message.data() // 33 bytes -> [123, 34, 99, 114, 101, 97, 116, 101, 97, 100, 65, 116, 34, 58, 53, 55, 49, 54, 49, 55, 56, 52, 49, 46, 52, 53, 48, 55, 52, 52, 48, 51, 125]
let jsonString = try! message.string()  // {"createdAt":571617841.45074403}"
```

Now you can pass a custom encoder to your method to format your Date in a human readable format:

```
let message = ["createdAt": Date()]
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .iso8601
let jsonString = try! message.string(using: encoder)  // "{"createdAt":"2019-02-11T22:48:19Z"}"
```

Now using a custom Message structure

```
struct Message: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let createdAt: Date
    let sender, title, body: String
}
```

---

```
extension Encodable {
    func sendDataToServer(using encoder: JSONEncoder = JSONEncoder()) throws {
        print(self, terminator: "\n\n")
        // Don't handle the error here. Propagate the error.
        let data = try self.data(using: encoder)
        print(data.string!)
        // following the code to upload the data to the server
        print("Message was successfully sent")
    }
}
```

---

```
let message = Message(id: 1, createdAt: Date(), sender: "user@company.com", title: "Lorem Ipsum", body: """
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
""")
```

---

```
let iso8601 = JSONEncoder()
iso8601.dateEncodingStrategy = .iso8601
iso8601.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
do {
    try message.sendDataToServer(using: iso8601)
} catch {
    // handle all errors
    print(error)
}
```

---

This will print

```
Message(id: 1, createdAt: 2019-02-11 23:57:31 +0000, sender: "user@company.com", title: "Lorem Ipsum", body: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.")

{
  "body" : "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
  "id" : 1,
  "sender" : "user@company.com",
  "title" : "Lorem Ipsum",
  "createdAt" : "2019-02-11T23:57:31Z"
}
now just add the code to send the json data to the server
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use generic function with generic type `Encodable`

You can't

```
func toData(object: Encodable) throws -> Data {
  let encoder = JSONEncoder()
  return try encoder.encode(object) // Cannot invoke 'encode' with an argument list of type '(Encodable)'
}
```

You can

```
func toData<T: Encodable>(object: T) throws -> Data {
  let encoder = JSONEncoder()
  return try encoder.encode(object)
}
```

Comment: I had big hopes for this but same error: `
let bufferReq: Encodable
func toData<T: Encodable>(object: T) throws -> Data {
  let encoder = JSONEncoder()
  return try encoder.encode(object)
}
do {
  let foo = toData(object: bufferReq) // still has same error
`