# Swift 4 collection of Codable objects

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, generics, protocols

I have a `Codable` class with a variable that holds a dictionary with `String` keys and values that may be `String`s, `Int`s or custom structs conforming to `Codable`. My question is:

How do I define a dictionary with values that are `Codable`?

I hoped it would be enough to say

```
var data: [String: Codable] = [:]
```

but apparently that makes my class no longer conform to `Codable`. I think the problem here is the same as I had here, where I am passing a protocol rather than an object constrained by the protocol

> [Using JSON Encoder to encode a variable with Codable as type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053060/using-json-encoder-to-encode-a-variable-with-codable-as-type)

So presumably I would need a constrained generic type, something like `AnyObject<Codable>` but that's not possible.

**EDIT: Answer**

So since this can't be done as per the accepted answer, I am resorting to a struct with dictionaries for each data type

```
struct CodableData {
    var ints: [String: Int]
    var strings: [String: String]
    //...

    init() {
       ints = [:]
       strings = [:]
    }
}

var data = CodableData()
```

Comment: And what does this really have to do with Codable? Isn't this really about protocols and types in Swift?

Comment: The issue here is that you are using `Codable` as an existential type in the dictionary. You're right in that you need to constrain the type to something, but even `AnyObject<Codable>` wouldn't be it — you need something _concrete_, like `Int` or `String`. Are there limits on the types your dictionary will contain? And what do you expect to have happen on decode?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of my https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Swift collection contains just one type, and for it to be Codable, that type would need to be Codable — not Codable the type, but an *adopter* of the Codable protocol. You need the type here to be some *one specific Codable adopter*.

Therefore the only way to do what you're describing would be basically to invent some new type, StringOrIntOrStruct, that wraps a String or an Int or a struct and itself adopts Codable.

But I don't think you're doing to do that, as the effort seems hardly worth it. Basically, you should stop trying to use a heterogeneous Swift collection in the first place; it's completely against the spirit of the language. It's a Bad Smell from the get-go. Rethink your goals.

Comment: Thank you matt, it seems you are correct. The thing is that I have the user entering a bunch of data, some text, some dates, some bools, etc, and need to store it somewhere. I guess I will just make separate dictionaries for each type I support

Answer (score 1):

I think the compiler is simply not smart enough to infer the `Codable` implementation automatically. So one possible solution is to implement `Codable` by hand:

```
class Foo: Codable {

    var data: [String:Codable] = [:]

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        // ...
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I don’t know whether you can change the `data` type to help the compiler do the work for you. At least you can pull the hand-coding to the problematic type:

```
enum Option: Codable {

    case number(Int)
    case string(String)

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        // ...
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        if let num = try? Int(from: decoder) {
            self = .number(num)
        } else if let str = try? String(from: decoder) {
            self = .string(str)
        } else {
            throw something
        }
    }
}

class Foo: Codable {

    var data: [String:Option] = [:]
}
```

Comment: It's not that the compiler isn't smart enough to do it for you — it's that you can't call `decode(Codable.self)`. As you show, you need to try to decode multiple _concrete_ types for this to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have any of you tried Generics in Swift?
Look:

```
public struct Response<T> where T : Codable {
        let ContentEncoding : String?
        let ContentType : String?
        let JsonRequestBehavior : Int?
        let MaxJsonLength : Int?
        let RecursionLimit : Int?

        let data : Data?

        public struct Data : Codable {
            let response : String?
            let status : String?

            let details : [T]?
        }
    }
```