# How to define variable with type of Codable?

Tags: json, swift, swift4, swift-protocols

I want to create variable with type of **Codable**. And later to use it in the JSONEncoder class. I thought that code from below should work fine, but it gives me error:

> Cannot invoke `encode` with an argument list of type `(Codable)`.

***How to declare codable variable that JSONEncoder will be taking without error?***

```
struct Me: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

var codable: Codable? // It must be generic type, but not Me.

codable = Me(id: 1, name: "Kobra")

let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(codable!)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053060/using-json-encoder-to-encode-a-variable-with-codable-as-type) is similar question how to pass Codable using function. But I am looking how to set Codable using variable (class variable).

Comment: use `Any` not `Codable`

Comment: @LeoDabus Then another question how to pass it to JSONEncoder?

Comment: Whats wrong with using `Me`?

Comment: have a look at this [Answer on CodeDump](https://codedump.io/share/0W4liDhIF1RM/1)

Comment: @LeoDabus I want that it will be more generic approach. If I will have another "You" struct and it needs to be assigned to codable variable.

Comment: @Ramis check the linked question. But anyway you will need to pass an instance of your Me struct. Not a codable or encodable.

Comment: @LeoDabus I added comment that it is not duplicate. What I want to avoid to pass Me struct.

Comment: I might be wrong but you can't

Comment: @LeoDabus I spend sever hours how to do it, but did not found solution. Could you please remove duplicate as it is not duplicate.

Comment: I still think it is a duplicate. Reopening probably won't make a difference. I will post the link here as reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053060/using-json-encoder-to-encode-a-variable-with-codable-as-type

Comment: @Ramis This is not possible to do — `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder` require concrete types, which `Codable` is not (a variable whose type is `Codable?` is called _existential_). Can you show your use case here? What else could go in this variable?

Answer (score 7):

Your code is all right, the only thing we need to focus is `Codable`.

`Codable` is a `typealias` which won't give you generic type.

JSONEncoder().encode(`Generic confirming to Encodable`).

So, i modified the code as below, it may help you..

```
protocol Codability: Codable {}

extension Codability {
    typealias T = Self
    func encode() -> Data? {
        return try? JSONEncoder().encode(self)
    }

    static func decode(data: Data) -> T? {
        return try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
    }
}

struct Me: Codability
{
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

struct You: Codability
{
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        var codable: Codability
        codable = Me(id: 1, name: "Kobra")
        let data1 = codable.encode()

    codable = You(id: 2, name: "Kobra")
    let data2 = codable.encode()
}
}
```

Comment: You solution save me!

Answer (score 5):

I created the same scenario as yours:

```
struct Me: Codable
{
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

struct You: Codable
{
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        var codable: Codable?

        codable = Me(id: 1, name: "Kobra")
        let data1 = try? JSONEncoder().encode(codable)

        codable = You(id: 2, name: "Kobra")
        let data2 = try? JSONEncoder().encode(codable)
    }
}
```

The above code is not giving me any error. The only thing I changed is:

```
let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(codable!)
```

I didn't unwrap `codable` and it is working fine.

Comment: Compile do not provide any error, but when executing it give an error: fatal error: Optional<Decodable & Encodable> does not conform to Encodable because Encodable does not conform to itself. You must use a concrete type to encode or decode.

Comment: That explains then. You need to use concrete types.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this way, maybe it helps on your case as well.

```
public protocol AbstractMessage: Codable {
  var id: Int { get } // you might add {set} as well
  var name: Int { get }
}
```

then created a method:

```
public func sendMessage<T>(message: T) where T: AbstractMessage {
  let json = try! String(data: JSONEncoder().encode(message), encoding: .utf8)!
  ...
}
```

Here I created a common protocol, and passed it as a generic type to my function.

Comment: Are you sure? Is that working? I wrote the same method but there is an error saying "Cannot invoke 'encode' with an argument list of type '(Codable)'"

Comment: @Sanju this is currently used on the project I am developing now.