# Swift JSONEncoder().encode for child object

Tags: swift

I have a parent class with several methods and attributes:

```
class Animal {
   var var1: ...
   var var2: ...

   func func1() {}
   func func2() {}
}
```

And Child class:

```
class Dog: Animal, Codable {
   var name = ""
}
```

I need to add to parent class a method, that will return result of `JSONEncoder().encode` for child class. Something like:

```
let dog = Dog()
dog.name = "Bob"
let jsonString = dog.jsonString() // {"name":"Bob"}
```

Can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to add this to parent class or do you want to have all animals have `jsonString` method?

Comment: If latter, then you can use conditional protocol extension

Comment: @MaximKosov I need that all animals have `jsonString` method or variable

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51058460/6630644

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a `String` with the result of `encode`…

```
extension Encodable {
    func jsonString() -> String {
        let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(self)
        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    }
}

let dog = Dog()
dog.name = "Bob"
dog.jsonString()

// {"name":"Bob"}
```

Comment: How to get this from something like: `dog.jsonString()`?