# JSONSerialization.jsonObject isn't accepting my parameters

Tags: swift, swift4, nsjsonserialization, promisekit

I'm attempting to Promise a Json object.

However, JSONSerialization.jsonObject isn't accepting any of my parameters..

```
class func deserialize<T>(data: Data) -> Promise<T> {
    let deserialized = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
        String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

    // Deserialize or try as String
    guard let object = deserialized else {
        return Promise<T>(error: APIError.InvalidJSON(data) as Error)
    }

    // Cast as T
    guard let objectT = object as? T else {
        return Promise<T>(error: APIError.JSONTypeMismatch(object, T.self))
    }

    return Promise(objectT)
}
```

I'm receiving two errors:

```
let desserialized = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
```

"Cannot invoke 'jsonObject' with an argument list of type '(with: Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions)'"

```
String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

"Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type 'Data'"

Comment: Seems like you have another `Data` class/struct that is conflicting with the standard Swift `Data` struct.

Comment: ...That was the problem! This question has been solved!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51058460/6630644

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to "RMaddy"

Seems like you have another Data class/struct that is conflicting with the standard Swift Data struct.

There was a pre-existing class that I named Data.