# Swift Encoding Technique for Custom nested Objects?

Tags: ios, swift

I am need to get encoding for the nested object

```
class person {
var name: String?
var phone: String?
var address: Address?
}

class Address {
var area: String?
var city: String?
}
```

I tried

```
let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(person)
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
```

but Address key value pair is not getting.

Comment: Would you like to update your question by including the missing code related to `Person` and `Address` classes?

Comment: To encode the classes with `JSONEncoder` you have to adopt `Codable`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51058460/6630644

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just implement `Encodable`

```
class Person: Encodable {
  var name: String?
  var phone: String?
  var address: Address?
}

class Address: Encodable {
  var area: String?
  var city: String?
}
let address = Address()
address.area = "Area"
address.city = "City"
let person = Person()
person.name = "name"
person.address = address

let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(person)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Person: Encodable {
    var name, phone: String
    var address: Address
}

struct Address: Encodable {
    var area, city: String
}
```

- conform your models which you need to encode to protocol `Encodable`
- types should start with big capital letter
- if you're sure that properites won't be `nil` don't make them optional
- you can make your models structs instead of classes

---

Then just encode your object

```
let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(person)
```

---

When you need print your encoded data, you need to convert them to `String`

```
let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(person)
let json = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
```

if you need to encode object with key `"person"` and person object as value, encode dictionary

```
let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(["person": person])
let json = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
```

Comment: Thanks Robert but the I need json { "person": { "name": "name",phone : "phone number" , "address": { "area" :  "area", "city": "city name" } }}

Comment: `Person` should be `Encodable` too.

Comment: @satishreddy, then do `encoder.encode(["person": person])`, where `person` is instance of `Person` type, and `encoder` is `JSONEncoder`.

Comment: @RobertDresler, because OP asks to encode **whole** `Person` in the comment just above. With all the fields.

Comment: @user28434 yes, in comment yes. But from question it wasn't clear