# Genericize method to encode a `Codable` protocol

Tags: swift, generics

```
import Foundation

protocol ProtocolA: Codable {
    var var1: String { get }
}

struct Type1: ProtocolA {
    var var1: String
    var var2: Int
}

struct Type2: ProtocolA {
    var var1: String
    var var2: Bool
}

func encode<T: ProtocolA & Encodable>(object: T) throws -> Data {
    return try JSONEncoder().encode(object as! T.Type)
}
```

Putting the above in a playground results in `error: argument type 'T.Type' does not conform to expected type 'Encodable'`

Why does this happen when I am saying that `T` has to conform to `Encodable`?

Comment: You don't have to typecast since T conforms to Encodable, `return try JSONEncoder().encode(object)` will work. Note that the compiler doesn't complain about T but T.Type

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54641181/2303865

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return try JSONEncoder().encode(object as! T.Type)
```

This means to convert `object` to the *metatype* of `T`. The type of the type. For example, 1 is an Int. But "Int" itself has a type, which is `Int.Type`, which is a metatype. Metatypes do not conform to Encodable.

You meant:

```
return try JSONEncoder().encode(object as! T)
```

But you really just meant:

```
return try JSONEncoder().encode(object)
```

since `object` is *always* of type T. That's its explicit type from the function signature. Since you also don't rely on ProtocolA for this algorithm, this all boils down to:

```
func encode<T: Encodable>(object: T) throws -> Data {
    return try JSONEncoder().encode(object)
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks that makes sense. 
What I'm really trying to achieve is:
`struct Container: Codable {var array: [ProtocolA] }`
Without having to switch over all the types that conform to that protocol in the `encode(to encoder:)` and `init(from decoder:)` methods

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler is actually complaining about the type cast your doing at the end which is converting `object` to the `metatype` of T, in your example either `Type1.Type` or `Type2.Type`.

From the encoding perspective, what the compiler needs to know is the model confirms to `Encodable` which is implicit in the  `T: Codable` statement.

```swift
import Foundation

protocol ProtocolA: Codable {
    var var1: String { get }
}

struct Type1: ProtocolA {
    var var1: String
    var var2: Int
}

struct Type2: ProtocolA {
    var var1: String
    var var2: Bool
}

func encode<T: Codable>(object: T) throws -> Data {
    return try JSONEncoder().encode(object)
}

let type2 = Type2(var1: "test1", var2: true)

print(type2)
```